# Populating Nested Arrays with Key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, search

I have a nested array structure that looks like this below. Lets call it arr:

[image: Nested Array Structure]

The innermost array has a key and value pair. But as it can be seen, the values are only from 3-7. I need to fill this innermost array with values 0-9 in the key column and populate them to 0 if the key doesn't already exist. I tried creating a separate array(target) with values [0,9] to check against but have been unsuccessful. I tried to do something like this but I am getting an error:

```
        var target = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    
        for(let i =0; i < target.length; i++){
            for(let j =0; j < arr.length; j++){
                for(let k =0; k < arr[j].values.length; k++){
                        if (miss_rate_arr[i] in rating_count[j].values[k].key === false){
                         rating_count[j].values.push({key:miss_rate_arr[i], value:0});
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(rating_count);
```

This is not only checking that particular value at that 0 location and I understand the problem. I am just not sure how to fix it. I am expecting the end result to look something like this below. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Where does this array come from? Do you create it in another part of your own code? If so, you should create it in the shape you want to begin with.

Comment: I actually ended up manipulating the array. It made job way easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what youre going for,
If you're going for a more general approach and want to keep the target array,
this is more like what you posted, and you'd need to sort it afterwards to get the array in the order you posted..

```
let target = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
for(let i = 0; i < target.length; i++){
    if (arr.filter(x => x.key == target[i]).length == 0){
        arr.push({key:target[i], value:0});
    }
}
arr.sort((a,b) => a.key - b.key);
```

But if target is always 0-9, you could skip the target array and just loop from 0 to the max key you're aiming for.
that way the test for the value is more simple (you can just check if the key matches the index) and since you have to add it at the correct index, you keep it sorted..

```
let maxKey = 9;
for(let i = 0; i <= maxKey; i++){
    if (arr.length > i && arr[i].key != i || arr.length == i){
        arr.splice(i, 0, {key: i, value:0});
    } 
}
```